# Can a dropdown box using PHP / MySQL automatically select what was last saved in the database with it?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on trying to get a dropdown box to display the most recently saved field each time I open a page for editing an item in an inventory. For example, let's say that my dropdown box selections are Iron, Copper, Gold, Silver, Titanium. The first time the dropdown box loads, I would like it to load in that order (the default order that I set it to). However, once a user submits a form that specifies a selection, I would like that selection to appear as the new default for the dropdown box (for example, if the user picks Gold, Gold will now display as the default). However - the new default that is selected and submitted can only appear for those fields which it is saved under (for example, since the user selected Gold, their preference is now saved as Gold and will appear as such under the field Necklace - however, Gold should not be the default for the fields Ring, Bracelet, and Earring when I open a page to view them).

Basically, I need a dropdown box that can save the option of the latest selection on a page after the form is submitted, while at the same time making sure not to affect the default order of the dropdown box across other pages. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you'll need per-user preferences (so that you can store the last selection for each user).

Depending on your set up this might be as simple as setting a $_SESSION variable (simply check against the session setting when you're outputting the select list HTML) although this will obviously only last for the duration of the user's time on the site.

For example:

```
<?php
// Example dropdown
$dropdownValues = array("One", "Two", "Eleventy");

echo '<select id="test" name="test">';
foreach($dropdownValues as $current) {
    echo '<option value="'.$current;
    echo $_SESSION['dropdowndefault'] == $current ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '>'.$current.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Alternatively you could use a cookie, or (if have user logins) a database backed preference setting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need a flag inside your database to mark it as last selected. Keep in mind that the flags need to be a 1:m relation since every user can have multiple flags. In your SQL, you just `ORDER BY` this flag so you have this as the topmost element.

```
SELECT * FROM table, flag_table
ORDER BY flag; --- not correct, just to get the idea
```

Another way is to keep the selected value in the session and when you use an array, remove it from it's current position and simply add it to the top.

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
//remove baz and add it to the front
$array = array('baz', 'foo', 'bar');
```

The SQL solutions seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

Store the options in the select box in an array within a session variable.  Each time the user submits the form, push the selected option to the front of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if you have logins or not, I'd recommend a session based solution to start with.

As different dropdowns need different defaults, why not an array?

```
$_SESSION['dropdownDefaults'] = array(
  'view_name' => id,
  'toplist_myDropdown' => 42
);
```

If your defaults need to survive over session lifetime, (browser close), the db-solution from drColossos would be fine, but then again you need logins...

Wouldn't recommend cookies as AV dislikes them.